# HTML margin does not react to css

Tags: html, css

I have a canvas and I want to place some text to its right. This is my HTML code:

```
    <div id="GL">
        <canvas id="GL-Surface" width="800px" height="600px">
            Canvases are not supported in your browser
        </canvas>

    </div>

    <div id="side_box">
        Sample text
    </div>
```

And this is my CSS code:

```
#GL {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;

    margin: 0px;

    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

#side_box {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

But for some reason, the sample text is placed under the canvas and if I inspect the site in chrome, I see, that there still is a margin. This is a screenshot from chrome:

[image]

The sample text on the bottom is supposed to be on the right.

Why does it still exist? I have set it to 0px.

Comment: What margin are you talking about, where exactly is that supposed to be? I don’t see any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` elements are block elements. This means, they will always force the next element to go under it.

We can fix this with the css property: `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`

There is also other ways to accomplish this, like with **flexbox** or **css grid**

You can read more about flexbox and css grid here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid

In the snippet I'm using the inline css property, and I've given the canvas a border for illustrative purpose.

```css
#GL {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#GL-Surface {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#side_box {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="GL">
    <canvas id="GL-Surface" width="200px" height="200px">
        Canvases are not supported in your browser
    </canvas>

</div>

<div id="side_box">
    Sample text
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, this is somewhat working, but the text is only on the bottom end of the canvas. How do I put the start of the text on the top of the canvas?

Comment: Flexbox makes it super easy. Try give it a read.

Answer (score 0):

By default div is block elements, changing it to inline-block fixes the issue-

```
div {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```